# Swift deinit is being called but object still not deallocating

Tags: xcode, swift, instruments

In swift I am getting the deinit function to print out a line saying that the object has been de initialized, but the object is still being reported as live in Instruments, allocations tool. I didn't think this was even possible. Is there a way to find out why it's not being freed? Or is there a way to find out what child objects could be holding it up?

Comment: could you solve it? I have the same problem

Answer (score 15):

> **Update:** For Swift 4, see the additional note at the end.
>
> **Warning:** This answer goes into some detail about the way the Swift runtime is implemented. The information here does not affect how you write code in Swift, except in some advanced scenarios. The main point is that from your point of view as a programmer, once `deinit` is called, the object is dead to you and you cannot use it any more.

The reason the memory is not freed is that objects in Swift are not necessarily deallocated (freed) straight away when they are deinited. Weak references to an object will cause the 'husk' of the object to stay allocated (in memory - you still can't use it!) until all the weak references have been zeroed.

Weak references in Swift are not zeroed immediately when the object is deinited, but they will be zero the next time they are accessed. That is, Swift zeroes weak references lazily. Here's an example:

```
public class MyClass {
}
var object = MyClass()
weak var weakObject = object
print (weakObject) // Points at a MyClass instance
object = MyClass()
// A: weakObject is not yet nil
print(weakObject) // prints 'nil'
// B: now weakObject is nil
```

After assigning `object` to a new instance (line 6), you would think that the weak reference to the original object would be zero, but it's not (yet). The object is *deinited* but stays *allocated* (in memory) until all the weak references are gone. At point `A`, a weak reference still exists, it's only on the next line when you try to evaluate the weak reference that Swift checks and notices that the object it references is deinited, so it zeroes the weak reference and then passes it to the `print` function to be printed. This mechanism needs the object's empty husk to remain allocated until all the weak references are gone. It is called a husk because all of its properties have been zeroed and released in `deinit` so it doesn't keep anything else alive (the amount of memory for an object is quite small, just enough to store its internal headers and members).

**Why and how?**

Each object has an internal weak reference count instead of a list of references that need to be zeroed. This is much quicker and less resource intensive to `deinit` because zeroing a list of weak references in a thread-safe way requires quite a long atomic/synchronized operation.

When the strong reference count reaches zero, `deinit` is called and the object enters the `deallocating` state. The run-time keeps the memory allocated because it needs to check the state of the object whenever a weak reference is accessed. Once all weak references have been accessed and zeroed (the weak reference count is zero), the memory will be freed and deallocation is complete.

Take a look at the implementation of `swift_weakLoadStrong` from the swift source code - this is the code that is inserted when a weak reference is accessed and made strong (for example to be assigned to a strong reference or passed into a function etc.). I have abbreviated it below. Look at the [original code on github](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/HeapObject.cpp) to see the full complexity of loading a weak reference:

```
if (object == nullptr) {
    __atomic_store_n(&ref->Value, (uintptr_t)nullptr, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    return nullptr;
}
if (object->refCount.isDeallocating()) {
    __atomic_store_n(&ref->Value, (uintptr_t)nullptr, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    SWIFT_RT_ENTRY_CALL(swift_unownedRelease)(object);
    return nullptr;
}
auto result = swift_tryRetain(object);
__atomic_store_n(&ref->Value, ptr, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
return result;
```

You can see that the object husk still exists in memory, and the mechanism that loads the weak reference (i.e. when you access it in your code) checks if it is deallocating, and if so it zeroes the weak reference, calls `swift_unownedRelease` to decrement the weak reference count and free the object if the count has reached zero, and returns `nullptr` (`nil`).

**Swift 4 Update**

Since Swift 4, weak references have an improved implementation that means the object husk no longer needs to hang around. Instead a small side-table is used and weak references actually point to that instead. The side-table contains a pointer to the real object and Swift knows to follow this pointer when accessing weak references. For a much more detailed explanation, read [this great blog post](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2017-09-22-swift-4-weak-references.html) from Mike Ash.

Comment: I am not sure how much of that is true,  apple docs says this `Deinitializers are called automatically, just before instance deallocation takes place` https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Deinitialization.html

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I like your scepticism, it's good for learning new things. See update, I have added more detail.

Comment: "Without going into too much detail (because I don't know all of it), what happens is that the object is deinited but stays allocated" No. An object whose `deinit` is called is going out of existence; it does not "stay allocated". The weak references to this object will need some bookkeeping, of course, and that will take some finite time, but it will happen before you have a chance to refer to the object through a dangling pointer, and that's all that matters.

Comment: @matt did I get my terminology wrong? The 'husk' of the object (i.e. the memory allocated for the object) absolutely does stay around after it is deinited until all weak references are accessed and zeroed. See: a) The swift implementation source code linked in my update; b) This exchange between Mike Ash, John McCall, and Chris Lattner where Mike fixed a thread safety issue in the implementation and they discuss the pros and cons of these husks hanging around: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-dev/Week-of-Mon-20151207/thread.html#243

Comment: What the OP is seeing can have nothing to do with what you're talking about, and what you're talking about amounts to a mere implementation detail. What I'm arguing is that one should not reply to the OP's question with an invisible behind-the-scenes detail. How Swift works behind the scenes may be fascinating to a few, but it should not be used to throw dust in the eyes of ordinary users.

Comment: @matt but this *is* what is happening here. He printed out from `deinit`, proving there are no strong references and `deinit` was called. However the object remains allocated because there's an unaccessed weak reference somewhere. If an 'ordinary user' is smart and curious enough to spot this behaviour in Instruments and ask about it - I believe they should get a detailed and honest answer explaining it, anything else is elitism. If my answer can be improved with some wording to mitigate confusing some users, please suggest those changes or edit them in. Sorry you didn't like it :(

Comment: Well, I don't insist on it. Your argument is a good one. Maybe I'm just being an idiot; it does happen. I've retracted my downvote. (I had to edit your answer in order to do that, sorry about that; just a dumb feature of Stack Overflow. Feel free to revoke my edit.) But I still wouldn't call the state of the object "allocated" while it is in its "husk" state. Maybe I'm wrong about that too...

Comment: No probs, it's a good edit :) I learned a lot researching this, hopefully the information and links will be interesting and useful for others.

Answer (score 2):

My suspicion would be that you are looking at different objects. Why do you believe that the object that called `deinit` is the same object that you're seeing in Instruments? Having more instances than you think you do (or just looking at the wrong one) is one of the most common causes of these kinds of confusion.

Is your `deinit` only the print statement, or are you doing anything else? In particular, are you doing anything that might accidentally retain you again? (I can't remember if that's well-defined behavior.)

Comment: I have the same problem and I don't really know why instruments is telling me it is a transient object, but deinit was called on it. Are there any reasons, why this could happen?

Answer (score 0):

Make dure you don't have any strong relationships with another object. Imagine the following:

```
class A {
   var b: B
}

class B {
   var a: A
}

a.b = xxx
b.a = yyy
```

If A holds a strong reference to B and B a strong reference to A, you create a strong reference cycle between them, and setting
a = nil 
won't call deinit because it holds a strong reference to b. You either set a.b to nil, or use the weak references (weak keyword) to solve this.

check apple's documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID51) for more details

Comment: Thread starter says deinit is called. If deinit is called nobody can hold a strong reference.

Comment: Yes, the retain count has to hit 0 for deinit to get called