# Deinit Called But Object Still in Memory

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting

I'm seeing strange behavior with the allocations instrument in Xcode 8 and Swift 2.3. I have an object (A) on which `deinit` is being called, all but one of the objects that A references are being deallocated (the one that isn't is a separate memory issue as far as I can tell), but the object continues to be listed as "live" and persistent in the allocations instrument. Additionally, when I try to debug it's retains, all I see is:

[image]

Note that I've confirmed deinit is being executed by:

- Adding a print line to the deinit method
- Adding a breakpoint to the deinit method
- Verifying that other objects that A references are de-allocated, and they receive a release (-1) ref count that claims to happen inside of the `A.__deallocating_deinit` method

However, for some unknown reason it appears to stick around.

Comment: Are you sure, there is no other reference of that object? As per ARC the object will not be deallocated until the reference count is 0. So might be you are keeping reference of that view some where else (in other VC).

Comment: If deinit is called (and has returned), then the object is almost certainly gone, no matter whether things it references are still around. Usually if you're seeing this kind of issue, there is second copy of the object that you weren't expecting. ("There's a second copy you weren't expecting" is actually the cause of a wide variety of seemingly impossible behaviors.) Check the memory addresses. But one other thing I'd look for is whether you're accidentally retaining the object in `deinit`. That can get you into a mess (but still *probably* wouldn't cause this symptom; I'm betting extra copy).

Comment: @RobNapier I did confirm that there is, in fact, only one object being created. `deinit` was being executed and still not freeing the object. While I still don't understand 100% why this problem happened, I've added the answer below that eventually solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a few more hours of searching I finally managed to (mostly) figure it out.

In this case, I have class A which has 6 properties, one of which is an instance of class B. Class A registers block callbacks with class B. Class B receives events from outside of the main run loop, on a separate NSThread that wasn't properly wrapped in an @autoreleasepool. As a result, Class B was being retained longer than intended, which resulted in its blocks with callbacks to A being retained longer than intended.

The reason I say "mostly" figured it out is because class A registered all those blocks with `[unowned self]`. For a still unknown reason, that seemed to be enough to allow deinit to be executed, but not enough to actually free the object. Wrapping the other thread in @autoreleasepool allowed the app to release B, which was then enough to release A.

Comment: I'm going to leave this answer unchecked for a bit to see if, based on this answer, anyone else is able to identify the "best" solution that actually solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for following up your own question with a possible solution you eventually found, more people should do this!

Comment: I experienced a similar issue and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39796073/6744473) cleared up the confusion for me. In my case, after going through my code I discovered there were closures with `unowned` references that weren't being released (a side-effect of a retain cycle). After eliminating the retain cycle, the objects deinitialized as expected along with their closures holding the `unowned` references, and the "husks", as put in the answer, appeared to disappear.